# Converting datetime value in a Tuple to Y-M-D

Tags: python, postgresql

In a previous question, I am trying to query a PostgreSQL for distinct date values and I received my query as: [(datetime.date(2020, 4, 27),), (datetime.date(2020, 4, 28),), ...]. I had asked for a way to convert each value into a date format such as 2020-04-27 and it was suggested to use strfttime() function but when I try to use this, I get the error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'. 

Any suggestions? My code is below:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "Select Distinct Datein from table Order by datein asc"
query = cur.mogrify(sql)
cur.execute(query)
datedata = cur.fetchall()
for date in datedata:
    d = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(d)
```

I am very new to Python.

Comment: you are getting a list of tuples, just try to apply strftime() on each first element of tuple , `d=date[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work ?

```
sql = "Select Distinct to_char(Datein,'YYYY-MM-DD') from table Order by datein asc"
```

Comment: I received the message no function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. I will research further.

Comment: I've fixed my anwser: function to be used on PG side is `TO_CHAR`.

Comment: This gave me ('2020-04-28',) which is the format I want! Not sure what the extra ',' is for but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for date in datedata:
    d = date.isoformat()
    print(d)
```

Comment: I received the same issue. tuple object has no attribute 'isoformat'

Comment: I understand now. You have a tuple that needs to be converted to a datetime object. Try this: mydate = datetime.date(d).isoformat()

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the message I got was an integer was required (got type tuple). I tried to convert but it didn't like that either. Had to be a string.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the tuple please?